# loadtxt ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, database, text

I have read other Questions with similar problems but none of the answers seem to help my case.

I have a .dat file that looks something like:

```
Some text about what the file is
    A         B         C       D        E
  1.150e+00 1.820e+00 1.000e+00 1.467e+00 1.200e-00
  1.100e+00 1.780e+00 1.000e+00 1.667e+00 1.130e-00
  1.050e+00 1.750e+00 1.000e+00 1.129e+00 1.560e-00
  1.000e+00 1.722e+00 1.000e+00 1.148e+00 1.729e-00
  1.800e+00 1.709e+00 1.079e+00 1.947e+00 1.595e-00
  1.600e+00 1.700e+00 1.012e+00 1.310e+00 1.768e-00
  1.400e+00 1.695e+00 1.548e+00 1.628e+00 1.317e-00
  1.200e+00 1.704e+00 1.512e+00 1.492e+00 1.233e-00
  1.000e+00 1.723e+00 1.778e+00 1.586e+00 1.772e-00
```

I have a .py code to plot E vs B

```
data = np.loadtxt('/Users/namesurname/folder/file.dat', delimiter = "  ", skiprows=2 )

with open(file.dat) as f:
    first_line = f.readline()

E, B = loadtxt(file.dat,unpack=True,skiprows=2)[4, 0:8], loadtxt(file.dat,unpack=True,skiprows=2)[1, 0:8]
```

But i get the error listed in the title:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

Any ideas n how to correct for that would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

is caused by the first block in your question. i.e.

```
data = np.loadtxt('/Users/namesurname/folder/file.dat', delimiter = "  ", skiprows=2 )
```

I'm going to ignore the other blocks.

Try removing the kwarg `delimiter`.

This works for me:

```
In : name = 'file.dat'
In : data = np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows=2 )

In : data
Out: 
array([[ 1.15 ,  1.82 ,  1.   ,  1.467,  1.2  ],
       [ 1.1  ,  1.78 ,  1.   ,  1.667,  1.13 ],
       [ 1.05 ,  1.75 ,  1.   ,  1.129,  1.56 ],
       [ 1.   ,  1.722,  1.   ,  1.148,  1.729],
       [ 1.8  ,  1.709,  1.079,  1.947,  1.595],
       [ 1.6  ,  1.7  ,  1.012,  1.31 ,  1.768],
       [ 1.4  ,  1.695,  1.548,  1.628,  1.317],
       [ 1.2  ,  1.704,  1.512,  1.492,  1.233],
       [ 1.   ,  1.723,  1.778,  1.586,  1.772]])
```